# Orchard multi-site localization

Tags: localization, orchardcms, culture, multi-tenant

Is there an easy way to associate a culture to a Tenant in Orchard. The aim is to build a website with a subdomain (or a domain) dedicated to a specific culture. This is something quite easy to achieve with umbraco, and is the only reason why I did not start yet to work with Orchard.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is fairly easy to set-up a culture for a specific tenant as there are finally two different websites. The inconvenient in this solution is that you have to reproduce the config for both each time.
http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/267530